# Browser keeps adding path in request in Django+Docker setup

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm not sure how this is happening, but the browser keeps adding the path (/code) where the Django app is stored in the container. If I make a curl request to the same url, it works fine.

[image]

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

and this is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env.dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, kinda ridiculous, but it was missing a forward slash at the end of the url. I thought Django would append slash automatically [according to their docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#append-slash)

> APPEND_SLASH
>
> Default: True
>
> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.
>
> The APPEND_SLASH setting is only used if CommonMiddleware is installed (see Middleware). See also PREPEND_WWW.